# Should I expect any changes if I switch the OS from Windows Server 2008 to Windows Server R2 in Azure?

Tags: azure, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, production-environment

Azure service configuration allows to alter [`osFamily`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee758710.aspx). Currently there're two options. Value `1` (the default) selects Windows Server 2008 and value `2` selected Windows Server 2008 R2.

I'm currently with the default (2008).

What changes should I expect if I just change to R2? Will it be faster? Will anything likely break?

Answer (score 0):

You should see this as if you were upgrading from Windows Vista to Windows 7, as described in this question: [What's the difference between Windows Server 2008, 2008 SP2 and 2008 R2?](https://serverfault.com/a/55422).

If you're building web applications the  largest impact will probably come from IIS. Windows Server 2008 uses IIS 7.0, Windows Server 2008 R2 uses 7.5. Read about the differences here: [What's New in the Web Server (IIS) Role (IIS 7)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560629%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

There's also a whitepaper that describes the new and changed functionalities and features: [Changes in Functionality in Windows Server 2008 R2](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10237).

To answer your question if anything will break I would say no (although something could always go wrong). I've deployed many applications to Windows Azure  and this never caused issues for me. When I upgraded from Windows Vista to Windows 7 it felt like I was using a more mature, stable and better performing system, and I would dare to believe the same applies to the server releases. And advantage is that you'll have new features available, like the Win32 support to mount VHD files (I think this relates to your VHD question).